# C# Cancel Method via calling a Method

Tags: c#, stack-trace

Hello StackOver Community,

I have the following  c#-code

```
void foo(int x)
{
  if(x<=0)
     {
       return;
     }
  do something more...
     .
     .
     .
}
```

I want to get rid of the if statement by calling a function which will "return" my foo function if the condition x<= 0 is met.

That is

```
void foo(int x)
{
  TerminateIfNegative(x);

  do something more...
     .
     .
     .
}

private ???? TerminateIfNegative(int a)
{
    if (a<=0)
    {
         "Make the method which called me "return" at the place I was called"
    }
}
```

I hope it is somehow clear what I want to do. Does someone have an idea?

Cheers,

Florian

Comment: the function is declared void as the return method so how can you return something?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is not return clear enough as a way to exit and terminate your code?

Comment: "I want to get rid of the if statement" Why? Seems pretty clear to me. Any different approach will make it less readable.

Comment: @jdweng I assume OP doesn´t want to return something, just exit the parent method.

Comment: The only practical way to "terminate" a method, other than with an if-statement that skips a bunch of code, is by throwing an exception.  Maybe not appropriate here, but exceptional conditions ought to have exceptional behavior.  The caller tends to need to know that a thing it asked to happen did not actually happen.

Comment: C# doesn't support _macros_

Comment: If any provided answers have helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

When a method's return type is `void`, this method does not return anything. There are only the following options to stop the execution of commands inside a void method:

- Throw an exception
- Use `return;` (which is the most common way)

If a negative value should **not** be passed as an argument to your method, then it is valid to throw an exception and [document that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/exception), in order callers of this method to be aware of this from the very beggining.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you´re asking for is common in procedural programming where you have a common linear program-flow from the very first line to the very last. This will apply to a line-by-line execution, which isn´t what OOP is about. There are good reasons we usually discourage use of `goto` and other stuff that controls program-flow as it will make it very hard to follow your code, e.g. when debugging. In fact this leads to spaghetti-code.

Imagine you want to debug your app in a few months. You step through your code until you reach `Foo`, step into it to sea what it does and - woaah, what is this - your debuger jumps out of `Foo` for whatever reason. It´s completely unclear **why** the method simply stops its execution.

What you seem to want actually is performing some checks on your user-input. So if your user types in a negative number your program should stop. It´s pure fine to throw an exception in this case, which basically indicates that a method cannot do what it is supposed to do. You could just create some `Validate`-method that throws an exception on ivalid input:

```
void Validate(int x)
{
    if(x <= 0) 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("x must not be negative");
}
```

This leaves it to the caller of the method how to handle an error. This way your `Validate`-method just **validates** the input. It should not **terminate** the calling method, which would break the single-responsibility-principle, wouldn´t it?

However throwing an exception in your case seems a bit like taking a a sledgehammer to crack a nut. The most simple and cleanest way is to do exactly what you want to avoid. Have an if-statement that terminates `foo` if the input is invalid:

```
void foo()
{
    if(!Validate(x))
        return;
}
bool Validate(int x)
{
    return x > 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually there is a solution for this. And a pretty ugly one. 
I'm aware that probably nobody will agree that this should be used, but I will present it anyway. Here you have the infamous goto solution:

```
void foo(int x)
{
  TerminateIfNegative(x);

  do something more...
     .
     .
     .

  EndOfFoo:
}

private void TerminateIfNegative(int a)
{
    if (a<=0)
    {
         goto EndOfFoo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? You cannot goto a label that is outside the scope of the method.

Comment: The goto is something I dont really suggest to use. Also as per above comment , you are outside the scope and most probably wont work.